# doxygen: vertical alignment of parameter / template parameters' names

Tags: css, doxygen

I'm documenting some C++ code using doxygen (version 1.8.13). When I am documenting function's parameters / template parameters, the result I get is the following one:

```
/*!
 * ...
 * @tparam Field The field to be decoded.
 * @tparam Container The container representing the binary string.\n
 * A valid container type must meet the following requirements:
 *  - define the member alias \c value_type, which must have size 1 B;
 *  - define a member function \c at(), accepting an integer index and
 *    returning a reference to the element at the specified index.
 * ...
 */
```

[image]

What I would like instead is that parameters' names are vertically aligned on top with the corresponding description, as in the following picture:

[image]

If it is possible, I would like to specify the alignment once for all the functions (e.g. through the Doxyfile or a DoxygenLayout file).

After a search on the web I did not manage to find any documentation on how to set the vertical alignment of parameters' names in doxygen. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_stylesheet) to modify the alignment of the template parameters:

```
table.tparams td.paramname { vertical-align: text-top; }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I guess I need to put this line in a file and write the filename next to the `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` tag. Does this setting apply to non-template parameters as well?

Comment: The class name for the table will probably be different. You can right click the parameter name in your browser and click "inspect element" to see a fully expanded CSS path. Look for `table.XXX` where `XXX` is the class name.